# More than one - singular or plural

Tags: grammatical-number

"When more than one threads are executed". Is this correct? How should it have been phrased?

Comment: Differently!!!!

Comment: It's pretty definite that you can't use a plural noun after "more than one". So it should be "more than one thread".